What does unbroadcastcount in getmempoolinfo mean?
What is the unbroadcastcount in getmempoolinfo? Does it track only the transactions from my wallet that are unbroadcasted? Or does it track all transactions that are not broadcasted which I may have received from peers.

This field counts transactions that have been submitted locally with the sendrawtransaction RPC or the wallet but have not yet been successfully relayed to at least one peer (as a response to a getdata message).
For more details you can check out PR #18038 which added the field.

Is it possible to get a list of such transactions?

Yes, if you call getrawmempool every transaction will have an unbroadcast field.
